# How to display image in jsPDF from input image upload

Tags: jspdf

I'm trying to work out how to upload in image using  and display it in my PDF.

In the image below you can see the data that I get when passing it down to the PDF-component I've made.

[Image data passed to jsPDF component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BjfL.png)

I've tried the doc.addImage(image, "png", ...) method, but I believe this is supposed to work with urls.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I made it work using the function URL.createObjectURL(image). Best regards, Ragnsan!